# jQuery find textarea in form loaded by .html() and apply a script on it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm writing a script for a small forum in which i want to load a form to be filled if (add new topic) was clicked. so far everything is good.. the question is.. i need to preform some script on the loaded form's textarea to add some HTML editor features.

my Script is :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div#new_topic_div').hide();
        $('a.new_topic_li').on("click",function(e){
        var parentID = $(this).closest('ul').attr('id');
        var form = "<form id=add_new_topic_form action='' method=POST>\n <input type=hidden id=cat_id value='" + parentID + "' /><table class=add_new_topic_form_table border=0>\n <tr><td colspan=2><?=tjcg_add_topic;?></td></tr><tr><td valign=top><?=tjcg_form_post_title;?></td><td valign=top colspan=2 ><input type=text name=new_topic_title id=new_topic_title><td></tr>\n <tr><td valign=top><?=tjcg_form_post_subject;?></td><td colspan=2 valign=top><textarea name=new_topic_text id=new_topic_text class=test rows='5' cols='45'></textarea></td></tr><tr><td class=add_topic_result></td><td width=50px><input type=submit class=submit_btn value='<?=tjcg_form_submit;?>' /></td><td class=form_result></td></tr>\n <table>\n </form>";
        e.preventDefault();
        var parent= $(this).closest('li');
        var checked = $(this).attr('checked_link');
        if (checked == 0)
        {
        parent.find('div#new_topic_div').html(form).show(200);
        $(this).attr('checked_link',"1");
        }
        else{
        parent.find('div#new_topic_div').html('').hide(200);
        $(this).attr('checked_link',"0");
        }
        });
    });
```

after the form is loaded into `div#new_topic_div` i want to apply the following script to the textarea field in the loaded form

`$("textarea").htmlarea();`

is that possible?

Comment: What is the problem? you mean you try add some script into textarea tag.. so where is the problem here you can try do load OR html or whatever to your textarea id..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this line:

```
parent.find('div#new_topic_div').html(form).show(200);
```

Just do this:

```
parent.find('div#new_topic_div textarea').htmlarea();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to put your html attributes in quotes eg

```
var form = '<form id="add_new_topic_form" method="post" action="...">';
```

That being said, you can ask the document to listen for events on dynamically created elements using jQuery's `.on()`. However, that's unnecessary for what you're trying to do. You can simply call whatever js code you need to after you've loaded your textarea into the DOM.

Example:

```
parent.find('div#new_topic_div').html(form).show(200, function() {
    $.getScript("some_script_for_textareas.js", function() {
        // Got script, do stuff with textarea
    });
});
```

or simply:

```
parent.find('div#new_topic_div').html(form).show(200, function() {
    // do stuff with $("#add_new_topic_form");
    $("textarea").htmlarea();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use https://api.jquery.com/on/

Example:

```
$("#container_id/and or class").on("focus", "#new_topic_div", function (e) {
     $(this).htmlarea();
});
```